# How to make multiplication and division counted first in my calculator?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, calculator

Hello guys im trying to make a calculator that is based on user scanner input, The calculator works fine for calculating from left to right but im having difficulties putting priorities in *,/ and () 
for example 3+(5*2)+1 should be 14 instead mine is 17, and then when i tried 
5+((2+1)*3)-1 it gives me weird error..
Can anyone help please? and how can i make my code appear more efficient and simpler thank you in advance.
So here is my code :

```
System.out.print("Input Equation : ");
                    n = s.next() + s.nextLine();

                    n = n.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                    char[] nans = n.toCharArray();

                    c = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) 
                        if (nans[i] == '+' || nans[i] == '-' || nans[i] == '/' || nans[i] == '*') 
                            c++;

                    char[] op = new char[c];
                    int[] num = new int[c + 1];

                    c = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
                        if (nans[i] == '+' || nans[i] == '-' || nans[i] == '/' || nans[i] == '*') {
                            op[c] = nans[i];
                            c++;
                        }
                    }

                    c = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {

                        if (nans[i] == '1' || nans[i] == '2' || nans[i] == '3' || nans[i] == '4' || nans[i] == '5' 
                         || nans[i] == '6' || nans[i] == '7' || nans[i] == '8' || nans[i] == '9' || nans[i] == '0') 
                        nus = nus + nans[i]; 

                        else if (nans[i] == '+' || nans[i] == '-' || nans[i] == '/' || nans[i] == '*') {
                            num[c] = Integer.parseInt(nus);
                            nus = "";
                            c++;
                        }
                        if (i == n.length() - 1){
                            num[c] = Integer.parseInt(nus);
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                        if (op[i] == '+') {
                            result = result + num[i] + num[i + 1];
                            num[i + 1] = 0;
                        }

                        else if (op[i] == '-') {
                            result = result + num[i] - num[i + 1];
                            num[i + 1] = 0;
                        }

                        else if (op[i] == '/') {
                            result = (result + num[i]) / num[i + 1];
                            num[i + 1] = 0;
                        }

                        else if (op[i] == '*') {
                            result = (result + num[i]) * num[i + 1];
                            num[i + 1] = 0;
                        }
                    }



                    System.out.print(" = "+ result);
```

Comment: Error because you are dont have any condition to check for the "(" or  " )"

Comment: It's really hard to help when your variable names are obscure, like `n`, `c`, `s`,`op`. You should give your variables meaningful names. Comments that explain what you are trying to achieve in your decisions or calculations won't hurt either. Beyond that, it's not enough to say "weird error". You should add the error including the stack trace to your question, and highlight the line where the error occurs with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a token (that is an argument for operator or simply a number), make sure that the next operator is not multiplication or division, otherwise, you want to calculate that one. You can achieve this by means of recursion easily.

Comment: How can i achieve this with recursion? if you dont mind to show me example of it.. thanks @Illiaz Akhmedov